# In jQuery function, hardcoded text works, but passed in parameter does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing

Given this function:

```
function highLightLi(className, textContent){

  if ( $("body").hasClass(className) ){

     $(".second-navbar").find("li:contains(textContent)").addClass("current");
  }
}

highLightLi('page-template-taller', 'Taller');
```

I know that the if statement passes as true, if I hardcode the textContent it does what I want and adds the class to the li, but no matter how I write it, it does not pass as a parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your find statement to this:

```
 $(".second-navbar").find("li:contains('"+textContent+"')").addClass("current");
```

You need to concatenate the string within the find statement, so you can dynamically add your string from whatever is passed into the function.

Let me know if that works!

Comment: This will of course break if `textContent` contains an apostrophe. Better to use `.filter` or something similar that accepts `textContent` as a parameter, not as a string to parse.

Comment: That did work for me thanks.Accepting when it allows me.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a combination of the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method for this. You want to avoid the string failing to escape where apostrophes are present in the nodes text.

```js
function highLightLi(className, textContent)
{
  
  if ( $("body").hasClass(className) )
  {
     //filter through all li elements
     $(".second-navbar li").filter(function()
     {
        //use trim method to remove white space
        var liText = $(this).text().trim(); 
        var containsText = false;
        
        //Check if node contains string parameter
        if (liText.indexOf(textContent) >= 0)
          containsText = true;
        
        //return if li text contains textContent parameter and add the class
        return containsText;     
        
     }).addClass("current");
  }
}

//escape the apostrophe
var searchParam = "your's";
highLightLi("page-template-taller", "Taller");
highLightLi("page-template-taller", searchParam );
```

```css
.current
{
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.page-template-taller
{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="page-template-taller">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="second-navbar nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"> Tall </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Taller </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Tallest </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> your's is Taller </a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```